# Problems inside my modern page, when adding a Modern News web part which have its source from a different site

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages

I am working on SharePoint online team site collection. and i created a new modern site page. where inside the modern site page, i added a News web part which have its News source from a sub-site inside the current site collection, as follow:-

[image]

but i am facing these major problems, with this News web part:-

1. when i click on the "+ Add" link and i added a new News page, i thought that the News item will be added inside the sub-site (the News source site !!), but the News item got added inside the current site!!
2. so to add a news item inside this web part, i have to go to the sub-site itself and from there to add a new News item page. then after around 10 minutes the new News item has been shown inside the modern page at the root site as follow:-

[image]

but I got another problem, is that when i click on the sub-site title link named "News & Announcements", i got redirected to the current site home page, instead of being redirected to the source sub-site home page.

so can anyone advice if there is a way to fix this problem? if i am inside a classic site page, i would use JavaScript.. but inside modern pages seems those types of customization is not possible (at-least we can not add custom java-scripts and custom css inside the modern pages)... so can anyone adivce on this please?